# Having one Main sticky Header with Multiple Sections of UICollection views? Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, header

I've got multiple sections of a UICollectionView, that change from a grid layout to list layout and I'm trying to use a sticky header to pin to the top and have it stay they while scrolling through all the different sections.
Is this possible?

Is a function similar to

```
 override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
```

That can choose which sections can have a heading and which shouldn't? or have one heading belonging to multiple sections?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection view's `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` and if it is flow layout use also `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`

Comment: check this: https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-sticky-section-headers-to-a-collection-view